# open and accept calendar invitations

Tags: calendar

How do I open and accept calendar invitations?  Phone is a Samsung Galaxy S  SCH-I500  2.3.4 firmware.  US Cellular carrier, I'm using gmail app and email app; neither recognize format.  phone's native calendar and google cal online.  All else synced and working beautifully.  3rd party software for ical attachments (buy me a beer guy) didn't parse correctly...

Comment: You need to be way more clear here.  What service are the invitations originating from?  Are you attempting to send a response?  Are you attempting to add them to your calendar (and which is that)?

Comment: Invitations sent from google calendar and from lotus notes calendar.  Attempt to view them fails; therefore can't accept and add to resident calendar - included on phone, synced to web google calendar

Comment: .ics attachments "not supported for viewing" even when they come from google calendar.  Still egg on google face IMHO

Comment: This is only partially the case.  Although there's no convenient way to do anything with an ICS attachment directly from your phone, you can have Google Calendar automatically add a corresponding event to your calendar when a .ics pops up in your inbox.  Just enable the setting, **Automatically add invitations to my calendar** in your **Google Calendar** settings (from the Google Calendar website).  Then when you receive a meeting invite, it'll already be in your calendar by the time you see the email.  You can then RSVP from Google Calendar (the site or the app).

Answer (score 1):

Use the free app [ics Databridge](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tools.icswrapper). It works perfectly. The size is just 25kB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Invitation Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleansoft.invitationplugin) to open ICS files directly in Google Calendar application. It can open ics invitations from email attachments or from files on sdcard.

It requires at least Android 4.x+ (Ice Cream Sandwich) to run.

**Note:** I am an author of this app.